# Referencing a range in a sheet with variable name in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

When I would like to import (query) many columns in another sheet I use this code:

```
=QUERY(sheet2!A1:D1;;)
```

Now I would like to make this formula a little dynamic making `sheet2` variable. So I put the string `sheet2` in a cell and make a reference to this cell using `indirect(address())`;

```
=QUERY(indirect(address(row();column()-1)&"!A1:D1"))
```

But this did not work.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TBvJ5Fcb3S3alMvU5wQTvzVX40g4PaiOBs_31lks4V0/edit#gid=0)

Please note: I know I could use

```
=query(indirect($A$1&"!A1:D1");;)
```

But I would the reference based on the position of the cell.

Comment: Why do you want to use something like `address(row();column()-1)` instead of a direct cell reference like  `A2` for the formula in `B2`?

Comment: @Ruben Because I need to reference to the cell by position and not by simple reference.

Comment: `A1` references, in opposition to `$A$1` references,  are relative to the cell that contains the formula and works to reference cells by position in many cases. Anyway, my answer includes alternatives to the use of `A1` references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

In the demo spreadsheet `B2` cell, instead of `address(row();column()-1)` use `A2` as an alternative replace the whole formula with `=QUERY(INDIRECT(OFFSET(B2;0;-1)&"!A1:D1"))`.

## Explanation

`address(row();column()-1)` returns `"$A$2"` not `"sheet2"`. The quotes are used to indicate that the result is a string value, not a cell reference.

An alternative is to use `OFFSET(B2;0;-1)` in the `B2` formula. This could be expressed in natural language as *get the value of the cell to the left of this cell (the cell that contains the formula)*.

The final formula is

`=QUERY(INDIRECT(OFFSET(B2;0;-1)&"!A1:D1"))`

### OFFSET()

From [OFFSET()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)

> #### Syntax
>
> OFFSET(cell_reference, offset_rows, offset_columns, [height], [width])
>
> - **cell_reference** - The starting point from which to count the offset
>     rows and columns.
> - **offset_rows** - The number of rows to shift by.
>
>   - **offset_rows** must be an integer, but may be negative. If a decimal
>       value is provided, the decimal part will be truncated.
> - **offset_columns** - The number of columns to shift by.
>
>   - **offset_columns** must be an integer, but may be negative. If a decimal
>       value is provided, the decimal part will be truncated. height - [
>       OPTIONAL ] - The height of the range to return starting at the offset
>       target.
> - **height** is ignored unless OFFSET is used in an array formula. width - [
>     OPTIONAL ] - The width of the range to return starting at the offset
>     target.
> - **width** is ignored unless OFFSET is used in an array formula.

## Remarks

Instead of `QUERY(range_reference)` to import a range of cells to another sheet use the array notation:

- `={sheet2!A1:D1}` or
- `={INDIRECT(OFFSET(B2;0;-1)&"!A1:D1")}`

## Demo

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kGgBltDL8ghKulMJab1T2Xzz0NMb20M5vDPfaFu7T-U/copy) is presented to show that  both approach, using QUERY() and using array notation, return the same result.

Note: The image shows comma as the parameter separator due to the default regional settings of the file.

[image: example]

## References

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you Rubén. But I need reference the cell by the position relative to the cell in which i write the formula. So I cannot use `B2` as in `={INDIRECT(OFFSET(B2;0;-1)&"!A1:D1")}`. I need to use `={INDIRECT(ADDRESS(same row;one column left)&"!A1:D1")}` or other formula.

Comment: @Francesco: I updated the answer. Hopefully it's now more clear.